# Yii Problems With The Testdrive Example

Tags: yii

I'm trying to create my first Yii application, step by step, with the testdrive example but I meet some problems.

When I try to create a new user, I obtain an error `CException`:

`UserController cannot find the requested view "_form".`

Comment: this means your view is missing from your controller's view folder..

Comment: Please update the title of your question, as this has nothing to do with the testdrive example . . .

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you've created a `protected/controller/UserController.php`.

From the sounds of it, somewhere in that code you have a call to `render` (or `partialRender`), that looks something like this:

```
$this->render('_form');
```

For this to work, you'll need a corresponding view file. Views should go in `protected/views/<controllerName>` and should be files that correspond to the view name you use.  In your case, you'll need a `protected/views/User/_form.php`.